# procedure & trigger postgresql add a condition doing it on only one line not all

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

first I create a trigger and its procedure but procedure is missing a sub-statement in the if part

```
create trigger a_financereconnomiser after update of prix_reel on a_financer execute procedure payetoeconomie() ;
```

the procedure is currently that one :

```
create or replace function payetoeconomie() returns trigger as $$
begin
if (select prix_estim-prix_reel from a_financer) >= 1 then 
insert into  economie (ref,designation,economie ) select ref*1000,date,objet,prix_estim-prix_reel from a_financer where prix_reel ;
end if ; 
end $$
language 'plpgsql' ;
```

If I try here to use it, the psql answers the function returns more than a unique line
this seems logical

so I need to add a "***and that column as changed during the update***" on column
prix_reel. here is the thing I don't understand how to do it in the procedure.

for information tables are build like :

source one :

```
 ref        | integer          |                 | not null  |            | plain    |                       | 
 date       | date             |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 dl         | date             |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 prix_estim | integer          |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 prix_reel  | double precision |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 paye       | integer          |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 objet      | text             |                 |           |            | extended |                       | 
 besoin     | integer          |                 |           |            | plain    |                       |
```

and destination one as :

```
 ref         | integer          |                 | not null  |            | plain    |                       | 
 date        | date             |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 designation | text             |                 |           |            | extended |                       | 
 economie    | double precision |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 commentaire | text             |                 |           |            | extended |                       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know the difference between a trigger function and a normal function.
In any trigger you should take advantage of the NEW and OLD variables. Both are record variables. In case of an update trigger, The NEW variable is the current modified record and the OLD variable is the original record before the update.
An update TRIGGER should usually return the NEW variable.

Here how I guess you want the trigger function  to look like:

```
create or replace function payetoeconomie() returns trigger as $$
DECLARE
  ec double precision;
begin
  ec = NEW.prix_estim - NEW.prix_reel; 
  IF ec >= 1 THEN
    insert into  economie (ref,designation,economie) VALUES (NEW.ref*1000, NEW.objet, ec);
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
end $$
language 'plpgsql' ;
```

Comment: we are just at marge of it ;   procedure complains on returning more than one line at once. I'm trying to adapt it.